# pdfrw - How to trim white space around the page

Tags: pdf, crop, margins, removing-whitespace, pdfrw

How can I find the space around a PDF page that is unused (white) with pdfrw in order to be able to trim it? Maybe if I can go through all the objects and find the closest coordinates to the border of the page...

Comment: Really no one here knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

pdfrw wasn't really designed to inspect pdf files that closely.  You should try pdfminer.  (Disclaimer:  I am the pdfrw author.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Very useful tool btw :)